# Authentication scheme in .net core calling wcf

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a .net core 2.1 web api that calls WCF service with windows authentication:

appsettings.json

```
"MyService": {
    "BasicHttpBinding": {
            "Security": {
                "Mode": "TransportCredentialOnly",
                "Transport": {
                    "ClientCredentialType": "Windows"
                }
            }
        },
        "UserPrincipalName": "mydomain/myUser"
},
```

mydomain/myUser - its a user which have permissions to call MyService and MyMethod()

code.cs

```
        using (var client = new ServiceClient<IMyService>(BasicHttpBinding, new EndpointAddress(new Uri(myServiceUrl), UpnEndpointIdentity)))
        {
            var result = client.Proxy.MyMethod();
            return result;
        }
```

And when I'm trying to call wcf service from my app I got an error:

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme
> 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate'

I've tried to indicate auth schema in startup.cs:

```
services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.Negotiate);
```

but no luck, exception is reproduced anyway.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use windows authentication, the client needs to provide windows credentials when calling the server:

```
 Service1Client service1Client = new Service1Client();
 service1Client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "Administrator";
 service1Client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "Password";
```

If the client does not provide windows credentials, an error will be reported:

[image]

Feel free to let me know if the problem persists.

**UPDATE**

Try to use **WCF Web Service Reference** to add a service reference to call the service:

[image]

```
 ServiceReference1.Service1Client service1Client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
```

**I will introduce my project for you, which is deployed in IIS:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2"/>
  </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="serviceBehaviour">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"  httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="HttpBinding_IService">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="1000000" maxArrayLength="163840000" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"/>
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <services>
            <service name="WcfService1.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehaviour">
                <endpoint address="Service" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="HttpBinding_IService" contract="WcfService1.IService1" />
            </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

This is web.config.

In IIS, I added two bindings for WCF, one is http, the other is https, and a certificate is required to use https:

[image]

We also need to turn off anonymous authentication and enable windows authentication:

[image]

**If the Mode is set to Transport, we also need to add htts binding and certificate.**

You can try the above steps to redeploy, hope you can succeed.

Comment: looks logical, but unfortunately it didn't help. Issue still reproduce            
`client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "myUser";`
`client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "myPassword";`
`client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = "myDomain";`

Comment: Is it because you provided wrong windows credentials?

Comment: Need to provide server-side windows credentials.

Comment: credential is valid, I put my own credentials. unfortunately, I cant provide screenshot of error, coz this issue reproduce only on test environment (locally it works fine). screenshot from logs: https://gyazo.com/9a31370146c72adeba5bb6d221cfff97

Comment: You try to use WCF Web Service Reference to add a service reference to call the service.

Comment: I see that you use UpnEndpointIdentity. I suspect it is caused by it, or it may be caused by the configuration file. I suggest you use WCF Web Service Reference to add a service reference and then call the service. This method does not require us to write a configuration file. Reduce the possibility of errors.

Comment: thanks for your answers, I'll try to rewrite my code using Service Reference.

Comment: Feel free to let me know if the problem persists.

Comment: I've rewritten code using Service Reference, but got the same error. seems like reason of this error is somewhere deeper, since the same code (using .net Framework 4.5) which deployed on same environment, works correctly

Comment: Can you provide some configuration of the server, it may be caused by the server, because the core does not support some functions of WCF:https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/blob/master/release-notes/SupportedFeatures-v2.0.0.md

Comment: If you use WCF, I suggest you still use the .net framework.

Comment: server configuration: https://gyazo.com/25abdef2ed103561c071e420347bbc15

Comment: I shared my project, I hope it can help you solve the problem.

Comment: it didnt help me( I found similar issue:https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6ad3fc11-0d4a-49a0-9f17-098acd823ac6/problem-setting-endpoint-address-url-dynamically-at-runtime-in-client?forum=wcf but it also didnt help me.Seems like the main reason of issue that client and server hosted on same machine

Comment: I don’t know what happened on your side, but this project works perfectly on my side.

Comment: And the client and server are not on the same machine.

Comment: Did you use https and certificates?

Comment: I think you can create a WCF service based on my configuration file above, which is deployed in IIS.

Comment: Another question is that your error is always "The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme'Negotiate'"?

Comment: I see that your configuration file is using self-hosting and baseadress is http instead of https.

Comment: yes, I always get the same error. Today I'll try to recreate my wcf service, with your configuration. Thanks for trying to help me, Im rly grateful to you for that.

Comment: Ok, please feel free to let me know if you encounter any problems.